# How to set multiple events on function

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

How do you call a function that allready has an event attached to it?

I want to be able to call the function with something like this:

```
statsDialog::statsDialog(..) : wxDialog(..) {
    updateStats();
}
```

Or, how to bind multiple eventhandlers to a function? For example call updateStats with the `wxEVT_SET_FOCUS` event AND when `UPDATE_STATS_BUTTON` is pressed. How can I do this without duplicating code (copying the updateStats function just changing it to `wxFocusEventHandler`)?

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(statsDialog, wxDialog)
EVT_BUTTON(UPDATE_STATS_BUTTON, statsDialog::updateStats)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

statsDialog::statsDialog(..) : wxDialog(..) {    
    // layout stuff
}

void
statsDialog::updateStats(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    // do stuff on dialog focus AND when UPDATE_STATS_BUTTON is pressed
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply have a function called `DoUpdateStats()` called from both the focus and button event handlers. This is particularly trivial when using C++11 with `Bind()`:

```
Bind(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, [](wxFocusEvent& e) { e.Skip(); DoUpdateStats(); });
btn->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, [](wxCommandEvent&) { DoUpdateStats(); });
```

Comment: Thank you! Works, but had to add & in the brackets for it to compile. `updateStatsButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, [&](wxCommandEvent&) { DoUpdateStats(); });`

Comment: The default capture node is not needed if `DoUpdateStats()` is a global function, but if it's a member method, you need to capture `this`. It's arguably better to do it explicitly than using the default capture mode however.